# Any Method to remove comment characters from JSON response in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, comments

I am new to JSON. Are there any methods in JSON parser to remove the comment characters from a response.

Eg. //{"response":"success".......

its SBJson for iPhone.
from  http://code.google.com/p/json-framework

Comment: You mention a JSON parser but fail to tell us which one.

Comment: its SBJson from http://code.google.com/p/json-framework

Comment: A decade later, this is one of those things that is now easy with modern Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON grammar doesn't allow comments.  That doesn't answer your question obviously, but I suspect you'll have to do some string manipulation and replace all those comment characters with empty strings and parse it with the JSON library only after doing so.

Comment: A decade later, this is one of those things that is fortunately now easy with modern Swift.  It's common to have "json" with comments in it on your servers, just during development.  You just add a couple lines of code to achieve it in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

## Nowadays, very easy to do this:

Here's how you get and parse actual json

```
// normal json no comments
func getStuff() {
  guard let url = URL(string: "http://you.com/x.json") else { return print("?") }
  
  let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
  aSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
  
  aSession.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
    guard let _ = self else { return print("woe") }
    guard let data = data else { return print("woe") }
    do {
      let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourStructure.self, from: data)
      localBlah = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: result.whatever)
      
    } catch let error {
      print(error)
    }
  }.resume()
}
```

Here's how you get and parse "json" which has simple comment lines:

## During development, remove #comment lines from "json":

Notice the line of code which decodes the `data` :

```
 let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourStructure.self, from: data)
```

Simply paste in these three lines of code, before, that line:

```
let s = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
let fixed = s.replacingOccurrences(
    of: "(?m)^#.*",
    with: "",
    options: .regularExpression)
guard let data2: Data = fixed.data(using: .utf8) else { return print("woe") }
  
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourStructure.self, from: data2)
```

So during development in your "json" on your server, you can have things like ..

```
"measures": [{
    "screen": "options",
    "topMargin": 25,
    #don't change topmargin anyone!
    "leftMargin": 12,
    #Note, Joe prefers 13!
  },
```

It's that simple.

---

## Important note on using regex:

Regex is a sophisticated process. The example regex used in this post simply means

> "Delete any full lines, which, start with a '#'

So, it only understands simple "full-line" comments.

How to write regex is beyond the scope of this QA.

When you pre-munge the text at `let fixed =`, use whatever regex or other technique you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parsers are very finicky about what is at the start of a JSON block to parse - they DO NOT like characters other than "{" at the start (at least that's what I found with TouchJSON, and it sounds like your case with SBJson is similar).

So just take your string and eliminate any characters before the opening "{", then you can parse:

```
NSRange startJSONRange = [myJSONString rangeOfString:@"{"];
startJSONRange.length = myJSONString.length - startJSONRange.location;
NSString *correctJSONString = [myJSONString substringWithRange:startJSONRange];

// parse correctJSONString
```

That will work, but the REAL fix is to tell whoever is sending you JSON to cut out the nonsense and send real JSON.